# Maven compiler plugin not copying generated classes to test-sources

Tags: java, mapstruct, maven-compiler-plugin

Maven compiler plugin is not copying the generated classes(mappers from mapstruct) to target\generated-test-sources\test-annotations. The directory is created but it's empty. The generated classes are copied to target\generated-sources\annotations only.

This is my maven-compiler plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>11</release>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.lombok.version}</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Where are your mappers located? The interfaces, not the generated classes.

Comment: @Filip in a package called com.example.something.mapper

Comment: Yes, but are they in your main sources or test sources?

Comment: @Filip they are in src/main/java, so in main sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location of the generated source is defined by the maven-compiler-plugin.

By default it will put classes generated by annotation processor in:

- target/generated-sources/annotations - When compiling classes from the `src/main/java` location
- target/generated-test-sources/test-annotations - When compiling clases from the `src/test/java` location

In order for you to see the classes under `target/generated-test-sources/test-annotations` then your mappers should be under `src/test/java`.

Comment: Thank you! It seems that I didn't understood how this plugin actually works. After I copied(just to test) the mappers(interfaces) in src/test/java, the mappers impl were generated. Not a good solution since I would have duplicated interfaces.

Comment: Why do you even need to have them in both places?

Comment: For testing and I want them to be injected.

Comment: You can inject classes from the main sources into your tests as well. The test location is only for classes that you need in your tests

Comment: Well, the implementation is not found by WELD(we use openliberty....) if the generated mappers are not in target/generated-test-sources/test-annotations...